# Playinfo changes when I click on Play or Pause - MPNowPlayingInfoCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, html, ios10

I have tried setting the playinginfo using the below method :

```
-(void)handleTheMediaPropertyList
{
    UIImage *artWork = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
    NSDictionary *nowPlaying = @{MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: @"SAMPLE TEST",
                                 MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: @"SAMPLE TEST",
                                 MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork:[[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:artWork]
                                 };

    [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:nowPlaying];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
}

-(void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

        switch (event.subtype) {
            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }    }
}
```

After playing the audio, whenever I go to the control center, playing info shows fine there. But when I PAUSE it playing info gets changed to and instead of showing Artist name which I had set above it shows the URL of the link where it is getting streamed from. And later after pausing then playing it again then same data is showed.

So for the first time when the audio is played the Playinfo shows the proper data, but once I open the control center and press PAUSE and PLAY then the playing info gets changed.

Please help me with this.